# Why does « facture » mean "bill, invoice"?

Tags: étymologie, latin

I am even more befuddled by the two separate « facture »'s on CNRTL. Which applies? They both look correct! [FACTURE<sup>1</sup>](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/facture) ( « manière dont une œuvre est composée ») stems from

> Empr. au lat. impérial *factura* « façon, fabrication », cf. l'a. fr. *faiture* « action de faire, création, production » au xiie-xvies.

[FACTURE<sup>2</sup>](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/facture) refers to

> 1540 *lettre de facture* (Ordonn. ds Rec. gén. des anc. lois fr., éd. Isambert, Decrusy, Armet, t. XII, p. 688). Dér. du rad. de *facteur** (agent commercial); suff. *-ure**.

'factor' means commercial agent in English too, but not an invoice! English
['factor'](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=factor) hails from

> French *facteur* "agent, representative" (Old French *factor, faitor* "doer, author, creator"), from Latin *factor* "doer, maker, performer," in Medieval Latin, "agent," agent noun from past participle stem of *facere* "to do" (from PIE root [**dhe-*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*dhe-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "to set, put").

Why do these ideas relate?

Comment: I guess they relate by their common ancestor, *facere* = to do/make. A "facture" is the act of making but also a document produced by a maker ("facteur").

Comment: *facteur* is also a [mailman](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/facteur.html) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the old times a ***[facteur](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/facteur?idf=dmfXhgYrmXart.revusYfaXdd;str=0)*** (or old French *faitor*, literally "doer", cognates with *faiseur*) used to create things, possibly with their hands, i.e. to *manufacture* them or more generally someone who "do" things. That leaves a wide range of interpretations. One of the meanings of *facteur* was "God", another one was "criminal" (modern French: *malfaiteur*).

The person selling or delivering the goods was also named *facteur* by metonymy. This gave the main meaning of *facteur* in modern French: postman. The other one is archaic.

Similarily, *[**facture**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/facture?idf=dmfXhgYrmXart.revusYfaXdh;str=0)* used to be what the facteur made or the way they made it. *Facteur* also gave another ***facture*** that means the documents attached to a shipment detailing its contents and at least nowadays, the price of each item.

[image]

*Le corps du droict françois*, 1600

The first meaning is not lost but is now literary, much rarer outside idioms like ***de bonne facture*** (of good workmanship).

The old French word *facture* was highly polysemic due to its root that means *to make*. See its [Anglo-Norman entry](https://www.anglo-norman.net/entry/faiture). Interestingly, *facture* gave the English "**feature**" with a shift in meaning.

A similar shift exists with the English "**invoice**" that comes from the French *envoi* (*Les **envoys***: the things being sent) that were both the goods and their bill, the latter being what English eventually kept.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate on "Similarily, facture used to be what the *facteur* made or the way they made it, then shifted to mean the bill attached to it."? Can you write more detail on this shift?

Comment: That was more a parallel evolution that a shift in meaning. Answer updated.

Comment: Maybe *Facture* is a diminutive for *Proof of Facture* ?

Comment: @Kii Close: *facture* comes from ***lettre de facture***.